# Node env variables: Do they persist?

Tags: javascript, node.js, package

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node app.js",
  "test": "NODE_ENV=test mocha --reporter spec"
},
```

---

`npm run test`

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "test") {
     console.log("BLAH BLAH")

}
```

`npm run start`

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "test") {
     // does this run?
}
```

what would NODE_ENV be here?  If I run `npm run test` and it sets NODE_ENV to `test` at runtime.  What I stop that process and then run `npm run start` ?  Will that `NODE_ENV` still be set to `test` from the previous command?

Answer (score 0):

Setting variables before the command affects only the command the follows. So they will be defined as long as the "test" script will run, but not when the "start" script will run.